# Data column values are not changing to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe,

```
df,
    Name    Stage   Description
0   sri      1      sri is one of the good singer in this two
1   nan      2      thanks for reading
2   ram      1      ram is two of the good cricket player
3   ganesh   1      one driver
4   nan      2      good buddies

tried df["Stage"]=pd.to_numeric(df["Stage"],downcast="float")
```

but still the values are same

Comment: I think you need `df["Stage"]=pd.to_numeric(df["Stage"],errors="coerce")`

Comment: I want the values in float

Comment: tried    df["Stage"]=pd.to_numeric(df["Stage"],errors="coerce")  but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.Stage.astype(float)` :

```
In [6]: df.Stage.astype(float)
Out[6]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
Name: Stage, dtype: float64

In [7]: df.Stage.astype(float)
```

---

Using `pd.to_numeric` is better as it handles the conversion to a float type that takes less memory.

**Example**

```
In [23]: df.Stage 
Out[23]: 
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
Name: Stage, dtype: int64

In [24]: import sys 

In [25]: sys.getsizeof(df.Stage)
Out[25]: 272

In [26]: sys.getsizeof(df.Stage.astype(float))
Out[26]: 272

In [27]: sys.getsizeof(pd.to_numeric(df.Stage, downcast='float'))
Out[27]: 252
```

In case there are bad data in df.Stage, coerce the value to `NaN`  `pd.to_numeric(df.Stage, errors='coerce', downcast='float')`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df["Stage"]=df["Stage"].astype(float)
```

If first solution failed because some non numeric data, use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stble/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for replace bad data to `NaNs`, so output are floats:

```
df["Stage"]=pd.to_numeric(df["Stage"],errors="coerce")
```

Comment: in this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html example, it is working but when I am trying its not changing to float'

Comment: Yes, then `df["Stage"]=pd.to_numeric(df["Stage"],downcast="float")` should working too, but astype is the best if all data are numeric.

Comment: Jezrael, can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724163/matching-keys-from-two-different-dataframes