# matching keys from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two dataframes,

```
df1,
    Name    Stage   Description                                 key
0   Sri      1      Sri is one of the good singer in this two   one
1   NaN      2      Thanks for reading                          two has
2   Ram      1      Ram is two of the good cricket player       three
3   ganesh   1      one driver                                  four
4   NaN      2      good buddies                                NaN


 df2,
    values
    member of four
    one of three friends
    sri is a cricketer
    Rahul has two brothers
```

I want to replace the df1["key"] with df2 values, if the key is present in df2.values.

```
I tried, df1["key"]=df2[df2["values"].str.contains("|".join(df2["values"].tolist()),na=False)]
```

But i am getting the output in the same order,

I want,

```
    output_df,
        Name    Stage   Description                                 key
0   Sri      1      Sri is one of the good singer in this two   one of three friends
1   NaN      2      Thanks for reading                          Rahul has two brothers
2   Ram      1      Ram is two of the good cricket player       one of three friends
3   ganesh   1      one driver                                  member of four
4   NaN      2      good buddies                                NaN
```

Comment: You want match `two has` with `has two` ?

Comment: yes, I want like that. that df1[key] can be anywhere in df2[values]

Comment: Hmmm, then all old solution cannot be used... :( because need only one word keyword or multiple words with same order... Need some fuzzy matching.

Comment: oh, what I can do now

Comment: It is completely new situtation, unfortunately. What is size of `df1` and `df2` ?

Comment: this is my sample data, but in my original data length of df1 will be more than 1000

Answer (score 2):

I'll use arrays of sets and use `<=` for subsetting testing and numpy broadcasting.

```
setify = lambda x: set(x.split())
v = df2['values'].values.astype(str)
k = df1['key'].values.astype(str)
i = df1.index

# These the sets
a = np.array([setify(x) for x in k.tolist()])
b = np.array([setify(x) for x in v.tolist()])

# This is the broadcasting
matches = (a[:, None] <= b)

# Additional testing that there exist any matches
any_ = matches.any(1)
# Test that wasn't null in the first place
nul_ = df1['key'].notnull().values
mask = any_ & nul_

# And argmax to find where the first set match is.  There
# may be more than one match.  I chose to use `assign`
# therefore I used `mask` to pass a slice of a series
# to target the correct rows.
df1.assign(key1=pd.Series(v[matches.argmax(1)], i)[mask])

     Name  Stage                                Description      key                    key1
0     Sri      1  Sri is one of the good singer in this two      one    one of three friends
1     NaN      2                         Thanks for reading  two has  Rahul has two brothers
2     Ram      1      Ram is two of the good cricket player    three    one of three friends
3  ganesh      1                                 one driver     four          member of four
4     NaN      2                               good buddies      NaN                     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, for the solution

Comment: could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305897/matching-rows-between-dataframes-in-pandas-in-python?noredirect=1#comment81578677_47305897 @pirsquared

Comment: how to make this work when I have comma separated values in keys

Comment: In the function I provided `setify`.  The `split` method can take an argument that specifies what to split onl  `setify = lambda x: set(x.split(','))`

Comment: thank you ill try, can you check that post pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305897/matching-rows-between-dataframes-in-pandas-in-python?noredirect=1#comment81578677_47305897