# matching rows between dataframes in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two dataframes,

df1,

```
 Names
 one two three
 Sri is a good player
 Ravi is a mentor
 Kumar is a cricketer
```

df2,

```
 values
 sri
 NaN
 sri, is
 kumar,cricketer
```

I am trying to get the row in df1 which contains the all the items in df2

My expected output is,

```
 values             Names
 sri                Sri is a good player
 NaN
 sri, is            Sri is a good player
 kumar,cricketer    Kumar is a cricketer
```

i tried, `df1["Names"].str.contains("|".join(df2["values"].values.tolist()))`

but I cannot achieve my expected output as it has (","). Please help

Comment: It should be a match, order is not a matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sets

```
s1 = df1.Names.dropna()
s1.loc[:] = [set(x.lower().split()) for x in s1.values.tolist()]
a1 = s1.values

s2 = df2['values'].dropna()
s2.loc[:] = [set(x.replace(' ', '').lower().split(',')) for x in s2.values.tolist()]
a2 = s2.values

i = np.column_stack([a1 >= a2[:, None], [True] * len(a2)]).argmax(1)

df2.assign(Names=pd.Series(
    np.append(df1.Names.values, np.nan)[i], s2.index
))

            values                 Names
0              sri  Sri is a good player
1              NaN                   NaN
2          sri, is  Sri is a good player
3  kumar,cricketer  Kumar is a cricketer
```

Comment: I don't want the output df separately. I want to add it to my df2

Comment: Then assign the result back to `df2`.  Or just assign to a new column directly instead of using `assing`.  Like `df2.loc[:, 'Names'] = pd.Series(np.append(df1.Names.values, np.nan)[i], s2.index)`

Comment: It worked, can you suggest me the best resource to learn pandas easily.

Comment: Nothing worthwhile is easy!

Comment: 1. Start [here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do) to get an idea of what pandas can do. 2. Give yourself a data analysis task. and figure it out using pandas.  Ask questions if needed.  3. Answer other people's questions.  Even if you don't post answers, read the questions and figure them out.  Read other people's answers to the question you just tried to answer. 4. Practice!

Comment: @piRSquared , this is not working properly when we have a space in df2 eg if i have a key `A room`, it is combining to `aroom` in `a2` I fixed that by removing the replace in `s2.loc[:] = [set(x.replace(' ', '').lower().split(',')) for x in s2.values.tolist()]` but  still it is not matching as it is splitting by a single word in s1. What can we do for this

Comment: hi, can you check this pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022851/how-to-map-two-rows-of-different-dataframe-based-on-a-condition-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
names =  [
    'one two three',
    'Sri is a good player',
    'Ravi is a mentor',
    'Kumar is a cricketer'
]
values = [
    'sri',
    'NaN',
    'sri, is',
    'kumar,cricketer',
]

names = pd.Series(names)
values = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['values'])

def foo(words):
    names_copy = names.copy()

    for word in words.split(','):
        names_copy = names_copy[names_copy.str.contains(word, case=False)]

    return names_copy.values

 values['names'] = values['values'].map(foo)
 values


    values          names
0   sri             [Sri is a good player]
1   NaN             []
2   sri, is         [Sri is a good player]
3   kumar,cricketer [Kumar is a cricketer]
```