# create dynamically dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of csv files in a folder, and I would like to create dynamically dataframes having the same name as the csv file

for instance I have the following files : AC201703.csv AC201703.csv AC201704.csv
I would like to load those file an put in dataframes having the same name e.g. AC201703 AC201704
I try to use exec like the following

```
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
   df = pd.read_csv(file,encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' )
   exec("%s = %s" % (file[:7],df))
```

but it didn't work, i get the following error

```
  File "<ipython-input-31-2d670638b427>", line 4, in <module>
    exec("%s = %s" % (file[:7],df))

  File "<string>", line 1
    A201610 =        A201610_fb_act_n_n_buy cust_key  A201610_fb_act_n_n LCELGST  \
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

it seems to assign to the variable A201610 the name of csv columns

Answer (score 3):

I think better is use `dict of DataFrames`:

```
d = {file[:7] : pd.read_csv(file, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') for file in glob.glob("*.csv")}
```

and then select `DataFrame` by keys - first 7 letters of filenames:

```
print (d['AC20170'])
```

---

But if dont want use `dict`s:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    globals()[file[:7]] = pd.read_csv(file,encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

print (AC20170)
```

Comment: can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305897/matching-rows-between-dataframes-in-pandas-in-python/47307029#47307029

Comment: @pyd - really hard, there is necessary some fuzzy matching and I have no idea for nice fast solution :( I try find some `difflib` solutions like `df2['values'].dropna().apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['Names']))` but it failed :(