# how to map two rows of different dataframe based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two dataframes,

df1,

```
 Names
 one two three
 Sri is a good player
 Ravi is a mentor
 Kumar is a cricketer player
```

df2,

```
 values
 sri
 NaN
 sri, is
 kumar,cricketer player
```

I am trying to get the row in df1 which contains the all the items in df2

My expected output is,

```
 values                  Names
 sri                     Sri is a good player
 NaN
 sri, is                 Sri is a good player
 kumar,cricketer player  Kumar is a cricketer player
```

i tried, `df1["Names"].str.contains("|".join(df2["values"].values.tolist()))`
I also tried,

but I cannot achieve my expected output as it has (","). Please help

Answer (score 2):

Using set logic with Numpy broadcasting.

```
d1 = df1['Names'].fillna('').str.lower().str.split('[^a-z]+').apply(set).values
d2 = df2['values'].fillna('').str.lower().str.split('[^a-z]+').apply(set).values

i, j = np.where(d1 >= d2[:, None])

df2.assign(Names=pd.Series(df1['Names'].values[j], df2['values'].index[i]))

                   values                        Names
0                     sri         Sri is a good player
1                     NaN                          NaN
2                 sri, is         Sri is a good player
3  kumar,cricketer player  Kumar is a cricketer player
```

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('sample_2.csv')

df2['values']= df2['values'].str.lower()
df1['names']= df1['names'].str.lower()

df2["values"] = df2['values'].str.replace('[^\w\s]',' ')
df2['values']= df2['values'].replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)

df1["names"] = df1['names'].str.replace('[^\w\s]',' ')
df1['names']= df1['names'].replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)

df2['list_values'] = df2['values'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split())
df1['list_names'] = df1['names'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split())

list_names = df1['list_names'].tolist()

def check_names(x, list_names):
    output = ''
    for list_name in list_names:
        if set(list_name) >= set(x):
            output = ' '.join(list_name)
            break
    return output

df2['Names'] = df2['list_values'].apply(lambda x: check_names(x, list_names))
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
values                        Names
0                     sri         sri is a good player
1                     NaN                             
2                  sri is         sri is a good player
3  kumar cricketer player  kumar is a cricketer player
```

**Exaplanation**

It's a fuzzy matching problem. So here are the steps that I have applied -

1. Remove punctuations and split to get unique words on both `df`
2. Lowercase everything for standardized matching.
3. Convert by splitting the string into lists.
4. Finally doing the matching via the `check_names()` function to get the desired output