# Get cell to left/adjacent column a well as Column value minus another column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 data frames and am wanting to get Column value for each row in the form of =B-A and =A for dynamic, ever changing data.

=B-A and =A

Dataframe1 with columns A and B

```
2          11                                  
2         19                           
11        15
```

Expected

```
2                        9
2                        17
11                       4
```

I have tried the following: For Equalling cell to left I have tried..

```
df1['b'] = df1['C'].str[:2]
```

For =C-B I have tried…

```
result = df['b'] - df['c'] 

df1 = pd.read_excel('C:/DAB.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols='A:B')

# Cell Equal to Left.
df1['A'] = df1['B'].str[:2]
```

As well as

```
# =B-A.
result = df['B'] - df['A']
```

I have tried lots of different methods but I can’t seem to get it to work.

This should also work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'b' : [2, 2, 11], 'c' : [11, 20, 30]})

# New column with results of difference
df['b-c'] = df['b'] - df['c']
```

Except that I am dealing with large, dynamic data set.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Problem is your sample working nice, but real data not?

Comment: Or need create new column with subtract and then delete second column?

Comment: Also `For Equalling cell to left` uses `df1['b'] = df1['C'].str[:2]` - but it select from string each values from 2.letter to end, but need strings, not numbers.

Comment: @jezrael Yes, I am not able to get this for working with real data.   I want to create a new column which =B as well as =B-A.  I can do this for small dataset but wanting to do this for columns as I have huge data to deal with.

Comment: Yes, so there is some error? What means does not work?

Comment: https://ufile.io/tefcg is data I am using.  df = pd.DataFrame({'b' : [2, 2, 11], 'c' : [11, 20, 30]})

df['b-c'] = df['b'] - df['c']
   result = df['B'] - df['A'] is giving me a large error message. I can append exact error message if you like but yes its not working.

Comment: In your excel is problem comma, need `.` for numbers

Comment: so need `df = df.replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)`

Comment: @jezrael df.1 is data I am look at and df.2 is ideal data/expected data.  I will just remove row 1 as its not important and use whole numbers.  Does decimals cause problems for pandas?  Interesting.

Comment: it is problem in python, because for decimal need `.` like `print(3.4)` for `3.4`, if use `print (3,4)` then get `3` and `4` numerrs ;)

Comment: And if use `print ('3,4')` get string `3,4` but it is no number, so imposible subtract..

Comment: I see.  How would I go about adding an addition =B column beside df = df1.replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float) as it doesn't like df1['A'] = df1['B'].str[:2]

Comment: Hmm, what about `df['c'] = df['a']` and then `df['d'] = df['b'] - df['c'] ` ?

Comment: I get  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'a'

Comment: It means there is no column a, check column names by `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: @jezrael [2, 11, 'Unnamed: 2', '2.1', 9]

Comment: Try add parameter `pd.read_excel('C:/DAB.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols='A:B', header=None)` and then instead `a` use `0`, instead `b` `1` like `df[3] = df[1] - df[2]`

Comment: It's not producing any errors though all the data appears as NaN instead of equalling cell column A for each row.  Wait nevermind I think that worked!  Let me re-test a few times

Comment: Check `print (df[1])` and `df[2]` if there are data

Comment: Is there way to add this new data =B and B-A to new dataframe.  Something like 
  df5 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df1.columns,index=[3,4].index) gives me a single column of NaN

Comment: No, it is wrong. the best is create new df by copy like `df3 = df.copy()` and then modify it by `df3[1] = df3[1] - df3[2]`

Comment: @jezrael Any idea how to read certain columns for csvs?  df1 = pd.read_csv('fwaf.csv', use_cols=[2,3], header=None) does not appear to work.  I imagine because csv's, I will have to use delimiters ","

Comment: need `usecols=[2,3]` - it read 3. and 4.th column - pythount counts form 0

Comment: @jezrael I have duplicates in all columns.  A lot in I e.g Tea, Tea, Fan, Fan, Power.   df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=[df1.columns[8]]) seems to give:     return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7.  Changing the number does not remove error. https://dropfile.to/wBWzkzV

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the help.  I noticed I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Tea' when I have other non numbered data but that likely serves as separate question.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46709403/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael That got rid of error message.  So df = df.replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float) tends to create that ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Tea'  while  df1[10]=df1[6].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)  displays 0     0.0
1     0.0
2     NaN      for  dfD= df1[10]-df1[6]   in https://imgur.com/a/USZX7 .  I am after K-G val